# Last-Value Property in HornetQ 2.1.2.Final

Tags: jboss, jms, jmx, hornetq

How does the **Last-Value Property** work in **HornetQ**?

I'm sending 4 elements to MyQueue just to test this property: 2 with a Last-Value Property defined, and the other 2 with a diferent Last-Value.

I thought that just 2 elements will be processed in the Queue: one of each Last-Value Property. But it doesn't seem to happen. The values in the JBoss JMX Console are like: MessageCount  = -4, DeliveringCount = -4, MessagesAdded = 4.
So, how does it works?

I'm using **Jboss 5.1.0.GA**, and I set the "last-value-queue" with true, in tue hornetq-configuration.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messageCount being negative was an issue with last-value-queues that is being fixed on the next version.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-466

with this commit:

https://github.com/clebertsuconic/hornetq/commit/a78836cdef4e28d76064500f57cb8e8a799da9bf

Other than the negative counter, everything works as expected.

Comment: So, in this version (2.1.2.Final), Last-Value-Queues are working fine besides the counters? Or even their behavior has issues?

Comment: well... 2.1.2 is an old release... you should upgrade to 2.2.X regardless... but I'm not aware of any issues besides the counters

Comment: I'm using JBoss 5.1.0.GA, and this version doesn't support that version of HornetQ (2.2.14 for example - I've tried). But I discovered that my problem with the Last-Value-Queue is in the Consumer - I'm using a EJB3 MDB. Do you know if there is any problem when I use this kind of Message Consumer? Thanks.

Comment: you could create your own Branch and cherry-pick the commit